# SCP log file to server

Tags: ssh, scp

Hello I am trying to SCP a log file to serve and I keep getting error

```
Warning: Identity file ids-east-1.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
ec2-11.com: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

I have tried all the solutions presented earlier but can't seem to figure out what's wrong.
The key I am using is :

```
scp -r -i ids-east-1.pem ~/int/resources/tests/tasks/lib/testing.log ec2-user@11.com:/home/wn/shelf/wrDb/fractions
```

Just a reminder- I am able to get a log file from this server using :

```
scp -i ids-east-1.pem ec2-user@11.com:/home/wn/shelf/wrDb/fractions/chrono.log ~/Desktop/aws_chrono.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one command works, but the other gives you:

```
Warning: Identity file ids-east-1.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

You are likely not running the commands from the same directory.  Try specifying the key path fully (something like):

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/ids-east-1.pem ...
```